# Copy/Paste Header from Template

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a template, and it has a page which contains images in the header. I want to copy those images to my ActiveDocument. I am using the following code:

```
Set doc = ActiveDocument
strTemplate = "C:\Users\rajtilak\Desktop\Report.dotx"
Set docTemplate = Documents.Open(strTemplate)
Set hdr1 = docTemplate.Sections(1).headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)
Set hdr2 = doc.Sections(3).headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)

hdr1.Range.Copy
hdr2.Range.PasteAndFormat wdFormatOriginalFormatting
docTemplate.Close False
```

This is working fine, except that it is not copying the header from section 1 but section 5 of the template. Is there any other way to copy the header from a Word file using VBA?

Comment: What if you set `hdr1` as a header of different type from [this list (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/wdheaderfooterindex-enumeration-word).

Comment: It worked! So what I did was, the template from which I was copying the header, since the page from which I was copying, I changed the code to:

    Set hdr1 = docTemplate.Sections(1).headers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage)

And for the rest, I changed the code to:

    Set hdr2 = doc.Sections(3).headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)

And it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Kazimierz Jawor, I got the code working. Here is the updated code:

```
Dim docTemplate As Document
Dim strTemplate As String
Dim hdr1 As headerfooter
Dim hdr2 As headerfooter
Dim doc As Document

Set doc = ActiveDocument
strTemplate = "C:\Users\rajtilak\Desktop\Report.dotx"
Set docTemplate = Documents.Open(strTemplate)
Set hdr1 = docTemplate.Sections(1).headers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage)
Set hdr2 = doc.Sections(3).headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)
hdr1.Range.Copy
hdr2.Range.Paste
docTemplate.Close False
```

Answer (score 1):

With objects like:

- Word's [`Sections`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/sections-object-word) *`(index_number)`* <sub>, or ,</sub>
- Excel's [`Series`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/series-object-excel)  *`(index_number)`*

...the *`index_number`* (annoyingly) **isn't always representative** of the objects "position number" or location, but we can confirm what's where with a sub like this:

```
Sub ListHeaders()

    Dim s As Integer, sec As Section, secs As Sections, outStr As String
    Dim h As Integer, hdr As HeaderFooter, hdrs As HeadersFooters

    Set secs = ActiveDocument.Sections
    For s = 1 To secs.Count
        outStr = outStr & "-----" & _
            "Section #" & s & " of " & secs.Count & _
            " : " & Replace(secs(s).Range.Text, vbCr, "") & _
            "-----" & vbCrLf

        Set hdrs = ActiveDocument.Sections(s).Headers

        outStr = outStr & "   Header 1: wdHeaderFooterPrimary   : " & Replace(hdrs(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text, vbCr, "") & vbCrLf
        outStr = outStr & "   Header 2: wdHeaderFooterFirstPage : " & Replace(hdrs(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).Range.Text, vbCr, "") & vbCrLf
        outStr = outStr & "   Header 3: wdHeaderFooterEvenPages : " & Replace(hdrs(wdHeaderFooterEvenPages).Range.Text, vbCr, "") & vbCrLf

        outStr = outStr & vbCrLf

    Next s
    MsgBox outStr

End Sub
```

... or text functions could be used to find the *`index_number`* for an object with specific text (or other attributes).